# Codeigniter: how to get data from array and store it in the database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file_name] => Chrysanthemum13.jpg
            [file_type] => image/jpeg
            [file_path] => D:/wamp/www/multipleImage/upload/
            [full_path] => D:/wamp/www/multipleImage/upload/Chrysanthemum13.jpg
            [raw_name] => Chrysanthemum13
            [orig_name] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
            [client_name] => Chrysanthemum.jpg
            [file_ext] => .jpg
            [file_size] => 858.78
            [is_image] => 1
            [image_width] => 1024
            [image_height] => 768
            [image_type] => jpeg
            [image_size_str] => width="1024" height="768"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file_name] => Desert6.jpg
            [file_type] => image/jpeg
            [file_path] => D:/wamp/www/multipleImage/upload/
            [full_path] => D:/wamp/www/multipleImage/upload/Desert6.jpg
            [raw_name] => Desert6
            [orig_name] => Desert.jpg
            [client_name] => Desert.jpg
            [file_ext] => .jpg
            [file_size] => 826.11
            [is_image] => 1
            [image_width] => 1024
            [image_height] => 768
            [image_type] => jpeg
            [image_size_str] => width="1024" height="768"
        )

)
```

I have to store values of **file_name** into the database table.
**My Model looks:**

```
public function galleryimages($image_data)
    {


        $data = array(
        'image' => $image_data['file_name'],

        );

            $this->db->insert('gallery', $data);
    }
```

I have to store all values in the **file_name** into the `image` of the table `gallery`. How can I make it possible? What all modifications are needed in the model.

Comment: What do you want? 2 entries for 2 value of `image` or 1 entry with 2 value separated  with `,` ?

Comment: actually I am trying to upload multiple images so i have to store all values of file_name. row by row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use insert_batch to insert all rows by one query.

```
 public function galleryimages($image_data) {
   $data = array_map(
                function($i) { return array('image' => $i['file_name']); },
                $image_data);
   $this->db->insert_batch('gallery', $data);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can do something like this in your project:

```
//get the numbers of elements of the array
$array_len = count($image_data);

//create the $data array, which I suppose you want to have a associative  key named 'images' to use it to insert to the database table. 
for($i = 0; $i < $array_len; $i++) {
    $data['images'][$i] = $image_data[$i]['file_name'];
}

//then insert each file name into the db. 
foreach($data['images'] as $image) {
    $this->db->insert('gallery', $image);
}
```

I'm assuming the var_dump() output you posted came from an array named $image_data.